# Typescript Type ‘string’ is not assignable to type" error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to split this number value, but first I'm converting it into a String, and I'm getting this error.

Type ‘string’ is not assignable to type ‘number’" error

This is my code:

```
export const roundWithPrecision = (
  value: number,
  decimalPrecision: number,
): number => {
  let valueString: string | number = value
  let valueSplit = valueString.toString().split('')
  return valueSplit;
};
```

Comment: `valueSplit` is an array of strings but the functions return type is just a single number

Answer (score 0):

I think the function returns a string and not a number as expected.

```
export const roundWithPrecision = (
  value: number,
  decimalPrecision: number,
): number => {
  let valueString: string | number = value
  let valueSplit = valueString.toString().split('')
  return valueSplit*1;
};
```

or

```
export const roundWithPrecision = (
  value: number,
  decimalPrecision: number,
): string => {
  let valueString: string | number = value
  let valueSplit = valueString.toString().split('')
  return valueSplit;
};
```

Comment: how can i make it return the string? I'm kinda new to typescript

Comment: You can try to return a number (as example 1 I gave) or change the expected return to a string (as example 2 I gave). Change ```const function = (): number => {}``` to ```const function = (): string => {}```